# Outer sum of two numpy arrays along specified axes

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have two `numpy.array` objects `x` and `y` where `x.shape` is `(P, K)` and `y.shape` is `(T, K)`. I want to do an outer sum on these two objects such that the result has shape `(P, T, K)`. I'm aware of the `np.add.outer` and the `np.einsum` functions but I couldn't get them to do what I wanted.

The following gives the intended result.

```
  x_plus_y = np.zeros((P, T, K))
  for k in range(K):
    x_plus_y[:, :, k] = np.add.outer(x[:, k], y[:, k])
```

But I've got to imagine there's a faster way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to add a new dimension to `x` and add using numpy broadcasting:

```
out = x[:, None] + y
```

or as [@FirefoxMetzger pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71929912/outer-sum-of-two-numpy-arrays-along-specified-axes/71930350#comment127104678_71930350), it's more readable to be explicit with the dimensions:

```
out = x[:, None, :] + y[None, :, :]
```

Test:

```
P, K, T = np.random.randint(10,30, size=3)
x = np.random.rand(P, K)
y = np.random.rand(T, K)
x_plus_y = np.zeros((P, T, K))
for k in range(K):
    x_plus_y[:, :, k] = np.add.outer(x[:, k], y[:, k])

assert (x_plus_y == x[:, None] + y).all()
```

Comment: I think this solution becomes more readable if we are explicit with the dimensions and write `x[:, None, :]` and `y[None, :, :]`. (`x[:, None, :] + y[None, :, :]`)